# Sorting json in python by a sub-key named release-date

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have json as below which I need to sort by release_date key. Please suggest me how can we do it. I main key in this json do have any fixed name and its the version which is a string.

```
{
  "2765.2.1": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-03-11 09:19:31 +0000",
  },
  "1688.5.3": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2018-04-25 14:36:41 +0000",
  },
  "2605.12.0": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-01-28 11:02:10 +0000",
  }
}
```

End result should be like this:

```
{
  "1688.5.3": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2018-04-25 14:36:41 +0000",
  },
  "2605.12.0": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-01-28 11:02:10 +0000",
  },
  "2765.2.1": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-03-11 09:19:31 +0000",
  }  
}
```

Comment: is the json already a dict or is it a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's sorted() function and the dateutil parser to parse the release_date string and use it as the sorting key:

```
from dateutil import parser as date_parser
import json

#skip this if your data is already a dict
MY_JSON = """
{
  "2765.2.1": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-03-11 09:19:31 +0000"
  },
  "1688.5.3": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2018-04-25 14:36:41 +0000"
  },
  "2605.12.0": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "architectures": [
      "amd64"
    ],
    "release_date": "2021-01-28 11:02:10 +0000"
  }
}
"""
#skip this tooif your data is already a dict
JSON_DICT = json.loads(MY_JSON)

sorted_items = sorted(JSON_DICT.items(),key = lambda item: date_parser.parse(item[1]['release_date']))

sorted_dict = {item[0]:item[1] for item in sorted_items}

sorted_json = json.dumps(sorted_dict,indent=4)

print(sorted_json)
```

PS: you might was to remove the comma after the 'release_date' as the json parser shows an error cause it expects another property after a comma

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just I had to skip the json conversion!